# Why do abstract base classes need abstract methods?

Tags: python, abstract-class

**Introduction**

Abstract base classes (ABCs) are used to create classes which are not intended to be instantiated directly, because there is no functionality, only a "template" of what attributes and methods are available. Instead, you create a child class that inherits from the ABC, implement stuff in the child class, and inherit from that. (The StackOverflow `abstract-class` tag defines them as follows: "Abstract classes are classes which cannot be instantiated. They exist to provide common functionality and interface specifications to several concrete classes.")

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def dream(self):
        pass
```

We cannot create an instance of `Animal` directly:

```
>>> Animal()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Animal with abstract methods dream
```

But we can make a subclass which implements `dream`, and instantiate that:

```
class Human(Animal):
    def dream(self):
        return "Electric sheep"
Human()
```

**Question**

Note that my ABC (`Animal`) both inherits from the `ABC` class and defines the `dream` method as being an `abstractmethod`. I don't understand why both are necessary.

**Details**

If I hadn't made the `dream` method an `abstractmethod`, then my ABC doesn't actually function as an ABC, because you *can* instantiate it, even though I was expecting it to complain to me about instantiating ABC:

```
class Animal(ABC):
    def dream(self):
        pass
barbapapa = Animal()  # Not a specific subclass of Animal. Still works.
barbapapa.dream()
```

Had I made `dream` an `abstractmethod`, but made my `Animal` class not inherit from `ABC`, I would still be able to instantiate it:

```
class Animal(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def dream(self):
        pass
barbapapa = Animal()  # Not a specific subclass of Animal. Still works.
barbapapa.dream()
```

And this works too! The `abstractmethod` decoration doesn't seem to do anything without inheriting from `ABC`.

I understand that a class inheriting from `ABC` shouldn't mean that you can't create instances of that class. (After all, the classes inheriting from my `Animal` class should be able to be instantiated, even though those classes indirectly inherit from `ABC` as well.)

But then why is inheriting from `ABC` necessary at all? Why not just made it so that you cannot instantiate *any* class that has `abstractmethod`s (or properties, or whatnot)?

Comment: TL;DR: abstract classes aren't a thing baked into the core syntax, like e.g. Java does. The core Python mechanics are pretty flexible and generic. To emulate abstract class behaviour at all, you need to "add" it through the `ABC` metaclass, and then mark all actual abstract methods as such with the decorator.